# getting extra value in JS array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to create from user input two arrays while calling a function. The issue is that I get an extra value in the array that I did not type in; it’s looks like a default value...

I have the following code:

```js
const NameArr = [];
const IdArr = [];

function getName() {
  const Input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const list_names = Input.split(", ");

  for (let i of list_names) {
    NameArr.push(i);
    IdArr.push(i);
  };
  console.log(NameArr, IdArr);
  return NameArr, IdArr;
};

getName();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick="getName();">Get Data</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why I get an extra value `[""]` in my arrays...

Comment: What is `return NameArr, IdArr;` supposed to do?

Comment: please change the form action to # or add a return false to the onclick action to prevent the demo code snippet redirecting away from the question after pressing the get data button.

Comment: _"I am not sure why I get an extra value..."_ - What _"extra value"_? You call `getName()` which adds the value of the input element at the time of execution - which is the empty string. Works as expected.

Comment: I think what @Louis.vgn meant to use an input value like "A, B, C" which will produce `["",  "A",  "B",  "C"]` instead of just `["A",  "B",  "C"]`

Comment: @Andreas that is what I don’t get then. To me, the time of execution of the `getName()` function is when you press enter or when you click the button... which in that case the value is not an empty string

Comment: The `getName();` inside the global script adds an extra `""` to both, globally defined arrays. Remove that line, it looks like a left over from something.

Comment: _"To me, the time of execution of the getName() function is when you press enter or when you click the button..."_ - Erm, no... o.O You execute it right at the end of the script

Comment: @IngoSteinke yes excatly

Comment: Ok I get it now.. It’s because the function is called in the `HTML` Right? I was wondering if I did not call the function in the js file where was the function call then...

Comment: @IngoSteinke But that's not what the script does... Remove the `getName()` call at the end and check the result in the console. There's no empty string.

Comment: You should only define the function in JavaScript, but not execute it after defining it. You only want it to be executed one the button is pressed.

Comment: and in order to execute it once the button is pressed, it is called in the `HTML` with the `<button onclick="getName();">Get Data</button>`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling getName() at the end of your code.

Inside getName you are getting the value of your input field which is initially the empty string ""

`const Input = document.getElementById("input").value;`

Then you are using the push() method which will push the empty string at first and now this is the content of your array

```
[""]
```

Later when you add other values and call getName() you will add the values on top of the already existing value

```
[""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on the comments.

the function call `getName()` at the end of the script calls the function right after it, even when the `button` hasn’t been pressed by the user. Therefore, it adds the empty value in the array since there is an empty value.

Just need to remove the `getName()`.

```js
const NameArr = [];
const IdArr = [];
Dict = {};

function getName() {
  const Input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const list_names = Input.split(", ");

  for (let i of list_names) {
    NameArr.push(i);
    IdArr.push(i);
  };
  console.log(NameArr, IdArr);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick="getName();">Get Data</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```